# Making a DC to AC converter at home

Tags: passive-networks, converter, supercapacitor, dc-ac

My idea was to build a DC to AC converter, and I want to make sure it's feasible:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGdg4T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A supercapacitor has very low voltage operating range from 1.2 to 3.3 V. When the switch is closed each supercapacitor is charged to 1.2 V with a total capacitance of 1 F.

When the switch is moved then the supercapacitors with L1 and R2 create a RLC circuit.

The frequency of the system is carefully placed at approximately 50 Hz. The energy of the system will eventually decay but the damping factor of this RLC circuit is at 25 mHz so the voltage stored in the supercapacitors will decay very slowly at a rate of e^-0.025t so we will have almost a sine wave at the output. Can this work,or is the 1 mΩ resistance, which is the parasitic resistance of all supercapacitors and the inductor too small?

Comment: Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: I know it works we did something similar in university im asking if it has any flaws(my reasoning).

Comment: @winny i dont think there is simulator which has space for 100 capacitors

Comment: @CartoonRyan 100 capacitors will be no problem at all. At run time this will be replaced with a single capacitor with a capacitance equal to 1/100 of the individual capacitor values. In practice, circuits with thousands of elements are not a problem.

Comment: Your series capacitors may not share equally, you will need some kind of balancing circuity.  Do you plan to put a load on the output?

Comment: You don't need to simulate 100 capacitors, you may simulate them as a single capacitor with 1/100 times the capacity and 100 times the parasitic resistivity.

Comment: Sure there is. Which have you tried which didn’t and how did you try to get around that problem?

Comment: @CartoonRyan My simulator for my thesis project handles on the order of 3500 capacitors representing various parasitics. It can be slow, but it handles it.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google ESR of a capacitor and inductor is in the order 0.01-0.1Ω,which means I have to update my circuit:The total sum of the ESRs is in the order of 1-2Ω

I want a signal with 50Hz frequency.In order for my circuit to sustain the oscillation for a practical amount of time the damping factor must be less than 1Hz which sets the value for the total inductance 2H.

[image]

So we put 10 electrolytic capacitors of 2mF in series.

So the circuit becomes like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3muEH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Cartoon Ryan - Hi, This answer isn't clear to me. Either **(a)** You correctly wrote it as an *answer*, because it really does answer your original question (even though it doesn't seem to do that to me). In that case, please clearly state that this is the solution, and come back in 2 days to "accept" this answer, to close the whole topic (self-answers can only be accepted after 48 hours has elapsed since asking the question).

Comment: [continued] Or, **(b)** You mistakenly wrote this as an *answer*, when in fact you still want more responses. In which case, this is an *update* and not an answer, and must be "edited into" your original question e.g. click "Edit" under the question, add this new information at the bottom, then delete this "answer". **Which applies here, (a) or (b)?** Thanks.